# AWS - how to convert list of tuples into multiple data frames (python - glue job)

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, dataframe, pyspark

I have list of tuples like

```
(
(('a1','a2','a3'), [[1,2,3],[4,5,6],[7,8,9]]),
(('b1','b2','b3'), [[11,21,13],[14,15,16],[74,84,94]])
)
```

This needs to be converted to multiple dataframes- one for each dataset.
for example `a1,a2,a3` must go to dataframe1, similarly `b1,b2,b3` must be converted to dataframe2.
Any easy way to iterate through within a dataframe?

currently I can convert 1st dataset in to dataframe using below:

```
x = spark.createDataFrame(data = r[0][1], schema = r[0][0])
```

r is where I have downloaded and stored the file. this reads only 1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9.

should i convert it into dic?

I want to be able to iterate list of tuples within dataframe

Answer (score 0):

Create a list of the dataframe and iterate.

```
data = [
    (('a1','a2','a3'), [[1,2,3],[4,5,6],[7,8,9]]),
    (('b1','b2','b3'), [[11,21,13],[14,15,16],[74,84,94]])
]

df_list = [spark.createDataFrame(data[i][1], data[i][0]) for i in range(0, len(data))]

for i in range(0, len(df_list)):
    df_list[i].show()

+---+---+---+
| a1| a2| a3|
+---+---+---+
|  1|  2|  3|
|  4|  5|  6|
|  7|  8|  9|
+---+---+---+

+---+---+---+
| b1| b2| b3|
+---+---+---+
| 11| 21| 13|
| 14| 15| 16|
| 74| 84| 94|
+---+---+---+
```